# C* may lose an update after INSERT IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: cassandra

I have the following code:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val cluster = Cluster.builder()
    .addContactPoint("localhost")
    .withPort(9042)
    .build()
  val session = cluster.connect()

  try {
    session.execute(s"CREATE KEYSPACE demoks WITH REPLICATION = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':1}")
  } catch {
    case _: AlreadyExistsException =>
  }

  session.execute(s"USE demoks")
  session.execute("DROP table IF EXISTS demo")

  session.execute(      """
                          | CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS demo (
                          |   id text,
                          |   data1 map<text, text>,
                          |   data2 map<text, text>,
                          |   PRIMARY KEY (id)
                          | ) WITH
                          | compaction = {'class': 'LeveledCompactionStrategy'}
                          | AND
                          | compression = { 'sstable_compression' : 'SnappyCompressor' };
                        """.stripMargin).one()

  val p1 = session.prepare("UPDATE demo SET data1[?]=?, data2[?] = ? WHERE id=?")
  val p3 = session.prepare("INSERT INTO demo (id,data1) VALUES (?,?) IF NOT EXISTS")

  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

  val id2 = "id2-"+System.nanoTime()
  session.execute(p3.bind(id2, Map("key" -> "value1-q1").asJava))
  session.execute(p1.bind("key", "value1-q2", "key", "value2-q2", id2))

  System.exit(0)
}
```

After execution of this snippet I'm just doing `select * from demo;` in `cqlsh`:

Usually the result is correct and expected:

```
cqlsh:demoks> select * from demo;

 id                 | data1                | data2
--------------------+----------------------+----------------------
 id2-61510117409472 | {'key': 'value1-q2'} | {'key': 'value2-q2'}

(1 rows)
```

But sometimes it may be different. Looks like that queries has been reordered and `IF NOT EXISTS` not triggered:

```
cqlsh:demoks> select * from demo;

 id                 | data1                | data2
--------------------+----------------------+----------------------
 id2-61522373234949 | {'key': 'value1-q1'} | {'key': 'value2-q2'}

(1 rows)
```

Could anybody explain me this behavior?

It's Cassandra 3.7 running in docker on Windows machine. I cannot reproduce this behavior under Linux nor Mac on the same machine and all another machines. I tried both docker and bare installations. Moreover, I cannot reproduce this even with bare installation on the same machine.

Comment: You should probably post your client code in order to understand what's going on.

Comment: Okay, I've posted a snippet.

Comment: Sorry again,you should also post your broken data.More precisely, you should post your client code and what you get back. It's hard to say without looking at that.

Comment: Ok, Will redo all the post and add samples.

Comment: @xmas79 I've revisited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is no guarantees how the insert, upsert statements you provide will end up in cluster. Most of the time you will get the behaviour you expect, but not always. This depends on some factors, what is the coordinator you are hitting, what is the time there.

You have two options, setting the time yourself on the statements you produce by using "using timestamp" or you can use batches so that you guarantee the order of execution of your statements:

```
// your code
Batch batch = QueryBuilder.unloggedBatch()
batch.add(binded p3)
batch.add(binded p1)

// now execute the batch
session.execute(batch)
```